# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

primera vez en una plataforma de estas... en fin.

Tengo un error, una excepcion en realidad que sale al querer persistir con em.persist de Hibernate en la clase ManagerImpl descripta mas abajo.

Esta clase ManagerImpl es llamada desde el ServiceImpl que es donde estoy llamando al metodo guardar que persiste, en el se paso como parametro la entidad (el objeto a persistir).

Ya chequeé que en la tabla a persistir los campos que estoy pasando como nulos tengan permito que sean nulos en la tabla también.

Estoy desarrollando en Java e Hibernate, en mi clase model de hibernate tengo lo siguiente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REPORTE_GENERADO")


public class ReportesGenerados extends EntidadBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="REPORTE_GENERADO_IDGENREPORTE_SEQ", sequenceName="SQ_REPORTES_GENERADOS",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="REPORTE_GENERADO_IDGENREPORTE_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ID_GENERACION_REPORTE")
    private Long idGenReporte;      

    @Column(name="TIPO_REPORTE")
    private String tipoReporte;

    @Column(name="ARCHIVO_REPORTE")
    private Blob archivoReporte;    

    @Column(name="ESTADO")
    private String estado;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="FECHA_INICIO")
    private Date fechaInicio;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="FECHA_FIN")
    private Date fechaFin;

    @Column(name="FDV")
    private String fdv;

    @Column(name="PERIODO")
    private int periodo;

    @Column(name="NOMBRE_ARCHIVO")
    private String nombreArchivo;

    public Long getIdGenReporte(){
        return this.idGenReporte;
    }
    public void setIdGenReporte(Long codReporte){
        this.idGenReporte = codReporte;
    }

    public String getTipoReporte(){
        return this.tipoReporte;
    }
    public void setTipoReporte(String tipoReporte){
        this.tipoReporte = tipoReporte;
    }

    @Lob
    public Blob getArchivoReporte(){
        return this.archivoReporte;
    }

    public void setArchivoReporte(Blob archivoReporte){
        this.archivoReporte = archivoReporte;
    }

    public String getEstado(){
        return this.estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(String estado){
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Date getFechaInicio(){
        return this.fechaInicio;
    }
    public void setFechaInicio(Date fechaInicio){
        this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
    }

    public Date getFechaFin(){
        return this.fechaFin;
    }
    public void setFechaFin(Date fechaFin){
        this.fechaFin = fechaFin;
    }


    public String getFdv() {
        return fdv;
    }

    public void setFdv(String fdv) {
        this.fdv = fdv;
    }

    public int getPeriodo() {
        return periodo;
    }

    public void setPeriodo(int periodo) {
        this.periodo = periodo;
    }

    public String getNombreArchivo() {
        return nombreArchivo;
    }

    public void setNombreArchivo(String nombreArchivo) {
        this.nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPK() {
        return getIdGenReporte();
    }
}
```

En mi ManagerImpl tengo el metodo que persiste en una base Oracle:

```
    @Override
    public void guardar(EntidadBase entity) throws ApplicationException {
        try {
            logger.info("guardando " + entity.getClass() + " con pk: " + entity.getPK());

            entity = cargarReferencias(entity);         

            if (entity.getPK() == null){
                em.persist(entity);

                if(entity instanceof Rol) {
                    Rol r = (Rol) entity;

                    for (RolCanal rc : r.getRolCanal()) {
                        rc.getId().setCodRolPk(r.getCodRolPk());
                    }

                    for (RolFdv rf : r.getRolFdv()) {
                        rf.getId().setCodRolPk(r.getCodRolPk());
                    }
                }
            } else{
                if(entity instanceof Rol) {
                    StringBuilder namedQuery = new StringBuilder()
                        .append("DELETE FROM RolCanal rc where rc.id.codRolPk = (")
                        .append(entity.getPK()).append(")");

                    Query q = em.createQuery(namedQuery.toString());
                    q.executeUpdate();

                    namedQuery.setLength(0);
                    namedQuery.append("DELETE FROM RolFdv rf where rf.id.codRolPk = (")
                        .append(entity.getPK()).append(")");

                    q = em.createQuery(namedQuery.toString());
                    q.executeUpdate();
                }

                em.merge(entity);

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            throw new ApplicationException(exception);
        }
    }
```

Y mi metodo serviceImpl que es donde mando a persistir (llamo al ManagerImpl):

```
        try{
            String anioCadena = Integer.toString(anio);
            String mesCadena  = Integer.toString(mes);
            periodo = Integer.valueOf(anioCadena+mesCadena);
            fechaInicio = new Date();

            repGen = new ReportesGenerados();

            repGen.setFechaInicio(fechaInicio);
            repGen.setFechaFin(null);
            repGen.setEstado("En ejecucion");       
            repGen.setTipoReporte(reporte);
            repGen.setArchivoReporte(null);
            repGen.setFdv(codFdv);
            repGen.setPeriodo(periodo);
            repGen.setNombreArchivo(null);
            abmMan.guardar(repGen); //<-------- Aca es donde quiero persistir
```

El tema es que tengo una excepcion en el ManagerImpl, en la linea:

```
                em.merge(entity);

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();  //<----- acá
            throw new ApplicationException(exception);
        }
    }
```

La excepcion:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Quien me podria ayudar? desde ya muchisimas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: ¿Verificaste que los nombres de columna de la tabla coinciden con los de la clase modelo?

Comment: Si, eso esta correcto, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el problema, no se había creado la secuencia en la base de datos ni tampoco se les asignó los grant necesarios. Luego de esta acción, la aplicación funciona de forma correcta. Muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Si esto es la solución al problema, considera aceptarla para que el que busque preguntas sin respuesta, no encuentre ésta en la lista, que ya está solucionada.